# git linux tools (sh) not found. to solve this problem you can set the correct path in setting

Tags: windows, git

Как исправить ошибку? Гуглил, но не могу найти ответ. У меня win10 с ubuntu LTS git extensions.
[image: git extensions]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а что это такое запускается?

Comment: git extensions .

Comment: если установлен git с сайта git-scm, то sh.exe можно найти где то здесь "C:\Program Files\Git\bin"

Comment: у вас в пути к sh в конце лишний слеш, может из-за этого?

Comment: Он не уходит, ставлю без слеша ,а он снова появляется

Comment: C:\Program Files\Git\bin - адрес, который указывать

Comment: ответьте и получите репутацию (C:\Program Files\Git\bin - адрес, который указывать)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Убери из пути "sh.exe", оставь "C:\Program Files\Git\bin". Должно будет заработать